# Obtaining information from a returned array - Confusion

Tags: php, class, function, return

Afternoon! I've looked around everywhere for an answer to this, I'm attempting to build a site for a company, and they would like a form of check to their external server. I have the class that checks for this information, and have confirmed it works by using print_r(), however I'm looking for something a lot more specific from the class - just to clarify, I am very new to PHP, and do not know a heck of a lot.

This is the class:

```
class MinecraftQueryException extends Exception
{
// Exception thrown by MinecraftQuery class
}

class MinecraftQuery
{
/*
 * Class written by xPaw
 *
 * Website: http://xpaw.ru
 * GitHub: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query
 */

const STATISTIC = 0x00;
const HANDSHAKE = 0x09;

private $Socket;
private $Players;
private $Info;

public function Connect( $Ip, $Port = 25565, $Timeout = 3 )
{
    if( !is_int( $Timeout ) || $Timeout < 0 )
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Timeout must be an integer.' );
    }

    $this->Socket = @FSockOpen( 'udp://' . $Ip, (int)$Port, $ErrNo, $ErrStr, $Timeout );

    if( $ErrNo || $this->Socket === false )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( 'Could not create socket: ' . $ErrStr );
    }

    Stream_Set_Timeout( $this->Socket, $Timeout );
    Stream_Set_Blocking( $this->Socket, true );

    try
    {
        $Challenge = $this->GetChallenge( );

        $this->GetStatus( $Challenge );
    }
    // We catch this because we want to close the socket, not very elegant
    catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
    {
        FClose( $this->Socket );

        throw new MinecraftQueryException( $e->getMessage( ) );
    }

    FClose( $this->Socket );
}

public function GetInfo( )
{
    return isset( $this->Info ) ? $this->Info : false;
}

public function GetPlayers( )
{
    return isset( $this->Players ) ? $this->Players : false;
}

private function GetChallenge( )
{
    $Data = $this->WriteData( self :: HANDSHAKE );

    if( $Data === false )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to receive challenge." );
    }

    return Pack( 'N', $Data );
}

private function GetStatus( $Challenge )
{
    $Data = $this->WriteData( self :: STATISTIC, $Challenge . Pack( 'c*', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ) );

    if( !$Data )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to receive status." );
    }

    $Last = "";
    $Info = Array( );

    $Data    = SubStr( $Data, 11 ); // splitnum + 2 int
    $Data    = Explode( "\x00\x00\x01player_\x00\x00", $Data );
    $Players = SubStr( $Data[ 1 ], 0, -2 );
    $Data    = Explode( "\x00", $Data[ 0 ] );

    // Array with known keys in order to validate the result
    // It can happen that server sends custom strings containing bad things (who can know!)
    $Keys = Array(
        'hostname'   => 'HostName',
        'gametype'   => 'GameType',
        'version'    => 'Version',
        'plugins'    => 'Plugins',
        'map'        => 'Map',
        'numplayers' => 'Players',
        'maxplayers' => 'MaxPlayers',
        'hostport'   => 'HostPort',
        'hostip'     => 'HostIp'
    );

    foreach( $Data as $Key => $Value )
    {
        if( ~$Key & 1 )
        {
            if( !Array_Key_Exists( $Value, $Keys ) )
            {
                $Last = false;
                continue;
            }

            $Last = $Keys[ $Value ];
            $Info[ $Last ] = "";
        }
        else if( $Last != false )
        {
            $Info[ $Last ] = $Value;
        }
    }

    // Ints
    $Info[ 'Players' ]    = IntVal( $Info[ 'Players' ] );
    $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] = IntVal( $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] );
    $Info[ 'HostPort' ]   = IntVal( $Info[ 'HostPort' ] );

    // Parse "plugins", if any
    if( $Info[ 'Plugins' ] )
    {
        $Data = Explode( ": ", $Info[ 'Plugins' ], 2 );

        $Info[ 'RawPlugins' ] = $Info[ 'Plugins' ];
        $Info[ 'Software' ]   = $Data[ 0 ];

        if( Count( $Data ) == 2 )
        {
            $Info[ 'Plugins' ] = Explode( "; ", $Data[ 1 ] );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Info[ 'Software' ] = 'Vanilla';
    }

    $this->Info = $Info;

    if( $Players )
    {
        $this->Players = Explode( "\x00", $Players );
    }
}

private function WriteData( $Command, $Append = "" )
{
    $Command = Pack( 'c*', 0xFE, 0xFD, $Command, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ) . $Append;
    $Length  = StrLen( $Command );

    if( $Length !== FWrite( $this->Socket, $Command, $Length ) )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to write on socket." );
    }

    $Data = FRead( $this->Socket, 2048 );

    if( $Data === false )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to read from socket." );
    }

    if( StrLen( $Data ) < 5 || $Data[ 0 ] != $Command[ 2 ] )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return SubStr( $Data, 5 );
}
}
```

I am trying to get data from the GetInfo() function, I have done some googling around about returning and functions, and tried some things:

```
                $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

                try
                {
                    $Query->Connect( 'ipgoeshere', 25565 );
                    $Info = $Query->GetInfo();
                    $maxPlayers = $Info['maxplayers'];
                    echo $maxPlayers;
                }
                catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
                {
                echo $e->getMessage( );
                }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this the completely wrong type of method. A solution would be fantastic!

Comment: your function received 3 arguments and you are giving only two $Query->Connect( 'ipgoeshere', 25565 );
give like this Connect( 'ipgoeshere', 25565, '' );

Comment: Do you connect with the correct IP? 'ipgoeshere' = the actual IP address? 2 args on connect is fine, as param list does specify default values.

Comment: @vidario I am yes, it connects and when I use print_r it prints the correct information, I'm just trying to specify down the information to certain items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$maxPlayers = $Info['maxplayers'];
```

should probably be

```
$maxPlayers = $Info['MaxPlayers'];
```

also you can try doing a

```
print_r($Info);
```

right after

```
$Query->Connect( 'ipgoeshere', 25565 );
$Info = $Query->GetInfo();
```

to see if the data did indeed make it to `$Info`, I can't seem to find anything else wrong with this :(

Comment: Haha, that was actually the issue! Thanks a lot for this and likely the amateur mistake!